# How to solve error: Exception setting "Value": "Value does not fall within the expected range." in powershell script

Tags: oracle11g, powershell-3.0

I am passing in a hash table of parameters for Oracle insertion. The contents of the hash table Value is an array. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception setting "Value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

When I try and add the value using array binding. I have a valid command object and I set the ArrayBindCount to the correct value. Here the code I am using and the output. This should work! Note that the $parameterValues variable contains my hash table that I am passing in:

```
$cmdObject = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sqlStatement,$connectionObject)
 $cmdObject.BindByName = $true

if($parameterValues)
 {
  ForEach($p in $parameterValues.GetEnumerator())
  {
   $cmdObject.ArrayBindCount = $p.Value.Count
   Write-Host ("ParameterName = ""{0}"" type = {1} Parameter Value Type = {2} Count = {3}" -f $p.Key, $p.Key.GetType().FullName, $p.Value.GetType().FullName, $p.Value.Count)
   $oraParam = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
   $oraParam.ParameterName = $p.Key
   $oraParam.Value = $p.Value
   $cmdObject.Parameters.Add($oraParam) | Out-Null
  }

  Write-Host("Number of parameters in `$cmdObject.Parameters = {0}" -f $cmdObject.Parameters.Count)

Write-Host ("Value of `$cmdObject.ArrayBindCount = {0}" -f $cmdObject.ArrayBindCount)
```

Here is the output and error I am getting:

```
    Value of $cmdObject.CommandText =  insert into regions (region_id, region_name) values (:REGION_ID, :REGION_NAME)
ParameterName = "REGION_NAME" type = System.String Parameter Value Type = System.String[] Count = 4
    Exception setting "Value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    At C:\Users\areum\Downloads\wd\Scratch\HelloPSWorld_functions.ps1:1615 char:4
    +    $oraParam.Value = $p.Value
    +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

    ParameterName = "REGION_ID" type = System.String Parameter Value Type = System.Int32[] Count = 4
    Exception setting "Value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    At C:\Users\areum\Downloads\wd\Scratch\HelloPSWorld_functions.ps1:1615 char:4
    +    $oraParam.Value = $p.Value
    +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

    Number of parameters in $cmdObject.Parameters = 2
    Value of $cmdObject.ArrayBindCount = 4
```

I just cannot get this to work! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

That exception is coming from Oracle.  It looks like you can only provide an int, not a string.  If your value was a string that can be turned into an int, use [int]$p.Value.  Otherwise, it might be an old school enum (just a number, not a proper structure).  If so, look up the direct translation of that enum to an int (try searching online for the specific string, and you should find documentation about it's real value).

The moral of the story is:

When you see an exception in PowerShell, pay attention to it.  It's rarely coming from the PowerShell layer, and commonly coming from the .NET just below the surface.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try this suggestion and see if it works. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question. I will post more feedback once I have tested your suggestion.